# How can I find max value of new create column?

Tags: sql, max, ssms, aggregate-functions

Say, I want to find the max value of the new created column 'new_salary'

```
SELECT id, new_salary = old_salary * 1.4
FROM employee_payment
```

I did this, but it did not work out

```
SELECT id, new_salary = old_salary * 1.4, MAX (new_salary)
FROM employee_payment
GROUP BY id
```

resulted in Invalid column name 'new_salary'. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to repeat the expression, or use a subquery.

For example:

```
SELECT id, MAX(old_salary * 1.4) as max_new_salary
FROM employee_payment
GROUP BY id
```

In this simple case, that's actually equivalent to:

```
SELECT id, 1.4 * MAX(old_salary) as max_new_salary
FROM employee_payment
GROUP BY id
```

If you were to use a subquery (which, here, is probably a less efficient option):

```
SELECT id, MAX(new_salary) as max_new_salary
FROM (
    SELECT id, old_salary * 1.4 as new_salary 
    FROM employee_payment
) t
GROUP BY id
```